# How to improve performance when creating a JMSProducer?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I've running a WildFly 10 instance with an embedded ActiveMQ Artemis on one instance.  On a second instance, I am connecting to the MQ via `pooled-connection-factory`.  However, when creating a `JMSProducer`, the performance is terrible; running jProfiler shows that it can take 4-5s to create the Producer.

```
@Inject
public JMSMessagePublisherServiceImpl(@JMSConnectionFactory("java:/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory") JMSContext jmsContext,) {
    this.jmsContext = jmsContext;
}

public void publishMessage(JndiEntry destination, Serializable object, String messageSelector, int priority, long timeToLive){
    if(destination == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("destination cannot be empty");
    }

    // check the priority level
    Validate.inclusiveBetween(0, 9, priority, "Priority must be between 0 and 9");

    try{
        // create a topic publisher
        JMSProducer jmsProducer =   jmsContext.createProducer();
        jmsProducer.setPriority(priority);
        jmsProducer.setTimeToLive(timeToLive);

        ...
        ...
```

The consumer JB node is configured as follows:

```xml
<pooled-connection-factory name="remote-artemis" password="${artemis.user.password}" user="${artemis.user.name}" entries="java:/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="remote-http-connector">
   <inbound-config jndi-params="java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory;java.naming.provider.url=${artemis.jndi.url};java.naming.security.principal=${artemis.user.name};java.naming.security.credentials=${artemis.user.password}" use-jndi="true"/>
</pooled-connection-factory>
```

What can I do to improve the performance?  Every call to the `publishMessage()` method creates a new producer.  Can the producers be pooled (ex: Apache Object Pool)?  From my understanding, a `JMSProducer` is not thread safe.  Is there a faster way to create a producer?

Comment: Does the profiler indicate what exactly is taking that 4-5 seconds when creating the producer? That seems excessive to me.

Comment: @JustinBertram Sorry - I got yanked off onto something a lot more critical, and haven't been able to analyze it more.  My Profiler dumps didn't work out to generate the details I needed, and I haven't been able to access to the PreProd environment to run more perf tests in the last 3 weeks.  I'll post an update as soon as I get more data.